# Mach-O Linker Error in iOS application

Tags: ios, objective-c, linker-errors

I am trying to run an iOS application which I have downloaded from github [here](https://github.com/fulldecent/FDWaveformView). I am getting Mach-O Linker error. I have searched around web but I found nothing.

I have added all the required libraries in  the Build Target. Error Stack goes like this

```
 Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
  "_CMAudioFormatDescriptionGetStreamBasicDescription", referenced from:
      -[FDWaveformView renderPNGAudioPictogramLogForAsset:done:] in FDWaveformView.o
  "_CMBlockBufferCopyDataBytes", referenced from:
      -[FDWaveformView renderPNGAudioPictogramLogForAsset:done:] in FDWaveformView.o
  "_CMBlockBufferGetDataLength", referenced from:
      -[FDWaveformView renderPNGAudioPictogramLogForAsset:done:] in FDWaveformView.o
  "_CMSampleBufferGetDataBuffer", referenced from:
      -[FDWaveformView renderPNGAudioPictogramLogForAsset:done:] in FDWaveformView.o
  "_CMSampleBufferInvalidate", referenced from:
      -[FDWaveformView renderPNGAudioPictogramLogForAsset:done:] in FDWaveformView.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: did u check in ' Link binary with libraries' also?

Comment: Did you check architectures (valid architectures and build active architectures only properties) of those dependencies?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I have successfully solved the problem. I was using the old version of XCode whereas project was expecting XCode 5. I have upgraded my OS to Mac OS Mavericks and my XCode to Xcode 5 and then everything worked fine.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it is a stupid answer/question, but you are really sure that you added the `CoreMedia` framework and it is linked in your Project?

EDIT:

With Xcode 4.6 is needed add CoreMedia Framework and set the storyboard compatible with Xcode 4.6.

With Xcode 5, the project compile without problem.

Comment: Yes Definately.!! I have checked it 4 times

Comment: Mmm, I just download the project and it run fine without any change.

Comment: Dont know what is the problem, I have wasted 2 days on it.

Comment: But, what are you doing? Did you only download the project from git and tried to run? Try to download the zip. What version of Xcode are you using?

Comment: Ya I downloaded the zip. XCode version 4.6.3

Comment: Ok, I tried with Xcode 5. Why do you use 4.6.3? I tried with that version and I have the same liker error... Let me check.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/42827/discussion-between-dcorbatta-and-mohit-sehgal)

Comment: Also, FYI there is a new Pod version 0.1.2 since then